# How many meaning does 前進しか許されない！ have?

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, kana

Is this supposed to be an expression, an idiom or a saying or proverb or whatever, because I have seen this used a lot. There seem to be no entries for "前進しか許す"

This video on youtube gives the translation for this sentence as:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quR5-FEaM9c&t=3m27s

私には前進しか許されないのだッ！ "I will never forgive them!"

But if you use google translate it gives:
私には前進しか許されない = I can only move forward

Comment: I think whoever subtitled it only really understood the word 許す, and then tried to guess a meaning based on the one part they understood. I've seen this a lot among amateur translators.

Comment: @Aeon Akechi Maybe its 許す 6. to give up (points in a game, distance in a race, etc.); to yield.  So probably 私には前進しか許されないのだッ！ "My only choice is to move forward without giving up!" or I could be completely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an idiomatic expression, and the subtitle on YouTube is wrong. It just means what it literally means, "I am only allowed to move forward" or "I have no choice but to move on".

Comment: Thanks for the help!