# Which 気力もつきかけている is appropriate here?

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, kana

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvBrve8BLog&t=2m57s

sm21891947 - スーパーメトロイド（ＳＦＣ） 店頭映像 | Super Metroid Promotional Preview

The official english captions for this sentence gives:

もう戦う気力も尽きかけている。= My powers grow with each battle.

but google translate gives

I'm running out of energy to fight.

Or maybe the translator who wrote the official english captions thought it was:

もう戦う気力も付きかけている

I realize that there was another post that is similar to my own, but that question seems to not have been answered:
[気力がつきかけていた: What meaning does かける have here? And which つき is this?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28960/%e6%b0%97%e5%8a%9b%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a4%e3%81%8d%e3%81%8b%e3%81%91%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%9f-what-meaning-does-%e3%81%8b%e3%81%91%e3%82%8b-have-here-and-which-%e3%81%a4%e3%81%8d-is-this)

Comment: 明らかに翻訳ミスですねえ。。。`official english captions` ってどこで見えるんですか？そのビデオには付いてないんですが。

Comment: @Chocolate https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quR5-FEaM9c&t=184s Super Metroid Official Nintendo Ad Reel 3/19/1994

Comment: ありがとうございます。やっぱり翻訳ミスですねえ。。他にもいくつかおかしいところありますね、「私には前進しか許されないのだ」を "I will never forgive them!" とか。。。

Comment: @Chocolate 私はその質問をここに投稿しました：":https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/83077/how-many-meaning-does-%e5%89%8d%e9%80%b2%e3%81%97%e3%81%8b%e8%a8%b1%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84-have

Comment: ☝あら、気づきませんでした。。。ちなみに「こんな薄気味の悪いところからは、早く逃げなければ。」「ここでやられるわけにはいかないんだよ」の訳も怪しいような気がします（訳した人は、「～なければ。」と「～わけにはいかない。」っていう表現を知らないみたい）。

Answer (score 1):

It's もう戦う気力も尽きかけている, or "I'm running out of spirit/energy to fight".

Simply, we never say 気力が付く, although we say 精力が付く.